# CQ5: How to programmatically find out the Resource given a URL?

Tags: aem, sling

According to ResourceResolver Interface:

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html

There are three ways to resolve either path or request to a Resource:

1. `Resource resolve(HttpServletRequest request)`
    Deprecated. as of 2.0.4, use resolve(HttpServletRequest, String) instead.
2. `Resource resolve(HttpServletRequest request, String absPath)` 
    Resolves the resource from the given absPath optionally taking
    HttpServletRequest into account, such as the value of the Host request header.
3. `Resource resolve(String absPath)`
    Resolves the resource from the given absolute path.

But if I have a random given URL string (e.g. `http://www.mycompany.com/whatever.html`), how do I programmatically find out the corresponding Resource of the given URL?

Comment: You've found the right API.  Is your question how you would use this in a JSP/Servlet?

Comment: The problem is that the said API does not take in a String of URL, only String of absPath.

Answer (score 5):

If the hostname/port from the URL is [mapped to a content repository location](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html) CQ will attempt to resolve the URL supplied.

In a servlet the ResourceResolver can be obtained from the slingRequest:

```
ResourceResolver resourceResolver = slingRequest.getResourceResolver();
String resourcePath = new URI("http://www.mycompany.com/whatever.html").getPath();
Resource res = resourceResolver.resolve(resourcePath);
```

Bear in mind that for short urls and domains like the above to work you would need to configure [mapping](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html) on your instance.

In a JSP, as long as you have called the `<sling:defineObjects/>`  or `<cq:defineObjects/>` tag you will be able to use:

```
<sling:defineObjects>
<%
    String resourcePath = new URI("http://www.mycompany.com/whatever.html").getPath();
    Resource res = resourceResolver.resolve(resourcePath);
%>
```

Some more information is provided in ["Getting Resources and Properties in Sling"](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-how-tos/getting-resources-and-properties-in-sling.html)

Test out on a couple of URLs you know are good.  For example:

```
Resource res = resourceResolver.resolve("http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx.html");
Resource res = resourceResolver.resolve("/content/geometrixx.html");
```

Both of the above should resolve to the same resource.

If you want to test whether CQ can resolve the URL you are providing, try the jcr resolver page in the system console
`http://localhost:4502/system/console/jcrresolver` to see if the url is mapped if it does not contain the full /content/.. in the path.  Any [mapped](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/mappings-for-resource-resolution.html) should be able to be resolved.

Comment: My experiment showed that the path in getResource(path) does not accept protocol/hostname/port at all. So the the above code is likely to return null.

Comment: The question is to figure out the Resource given an URL string. The absPath in resolve(String absPath) does NOT take in URL string. The example of using resolve() is not a solution.

Comment: You are right.  The resource resolver uses a helper that takes the URL and just uses the path from the url and ignores protocol/host/port.  I've updated the example to use java.net.URI to get the path before resolving.

Answer (score 0):

[ResourceResolver](http://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html) class was implemented to return Resource. Specifically, the resolve() functions exist for this type of resolution. However, even there are three overloaded resolve() functions, none of them takes in a URL String.

Given ResourceResolver takes in HttpServletRequest as input, if I can transform (adapt) a given URL into a HttpServletRequest using [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html), the problem will be solved. Therefore, the solution is to implement a ResolverRequest class which extends HttpServletRequestWrapper.

For the complete solution and code sample please see "[Programmatically find the Sling Resource from a Given a URL](http://www.hsufengko.com/1/post/2014/01/programmatically-find-the-sling-resource-from-a-given-a-url.html)"